# How to get only objects created by logged in user in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase in my Swift app. I create 2 different accounts and log in using them. At each of them I add some objects to Firebase. When I retrieve them Firebase returns me all objects. What I want to do is to get objects which are created by currently logged in user. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please show the structure of your Firebase DB

Comment: @NiravD https://pastebin.com/MqqiCnuY it is like here

Comment: Please update your question with a snippet of your firebase structure as text please, no images or links (links break). To get your structure use the Firebase dashboard->Three dots on right->Export JSON. There are a number of ways to secure your data but without understand the structure and use case. Maybe showing some code to demonstrate what you are doing with the data would help as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you have data that you only want a specific user to access, you should create a child node for each user. You can use the uid as the key:

```
-AK2459568560
  -Category
    -key
        -color
        -description
        -isOutcomeCategory
        -name
        -sum
  -Expenses
    -key
        -amount
        -category
        -date
        -description
        -initiator
        -isOutcomeExpense
        -name
-DSLKAF304028
  -Category
    -key
        -color
        -description
        -isOutcomeCategory
        -name
        -sum
  -Expenses
    -key
        -amount
        -category
        -date
        -description
        -initiator
        -isOutcomeExpense
        -name
```

EDIT: When you use this structure, you would attach a listener to the reference to the child with that user's uid.

In addition, it is important to configure your database security rules such that each user can only access the data you want them to access. One way to do this would be by limiting read privileges to the path in the database with their uid.

As Jay points out, you will also want to consider what information you keep under that uid. If you attach a listener to that path, it will download all the data nested within, so you want to avoid nesting data whenever possible using denormalization. You can learn more about database best practices in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data)

Comment: hmm can I create fields of custom types inside objects? Lets say user object has field cateogories which is also databse object? And can I create nested objects?

Comment: This documentation talks all about data structure https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data

Comment: @JenPerson While this is the start of an answer, [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) are more likely the correct answer. Also, your answer will likely lead to other issues as the paths are going to get too deep and make the data un-quereryable - therefore, [denormalization](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) would be in order. Also, it's not really accurate as creating a child node for each user doesn't have anything to do with getting data for just the current user.

Comment: Yes Jay, I should have gone into detail about database security rules and denormalization. Thank you.